# Should I have separate business and personal websites?

Tags: seo, keywords, personal-website, business

I have my business website - I am a web designer and developer, and also buy/sell websites/domain names.

As such my website links to 'Our sites' => the websites which we design and run as well as a variety of tools such as a domain whois tool. These are obviously relevant to the business.

As an individual, I like to travel and do white water kayaking as a hobby. I also have a degree in economics. I have thus created a blog on my business website where I write about domain names, web design, kayaking, travelling and economics.

I've just begun researching SEO and am looking into optimizing my business website. I don't actually directly offer any services to clients at the moment, my main aim is to have a business website which supports my websites.

If, for example, a potential advertiser on one of my sites checks out the business website, I want them to think professional, down-to-earth, quirky.

Given this, is having my business/personal interests intertwined a problem? For SEO.. on my homepage for example when I'm writing a headline and a paragraph about what we do.. what do I put? and how do I optimize for SEO with keywords and the like?

Further to the above, my company sponsors me and a group of acquaintances as a kayaking team.. as such my personal interests do sort of overlap (just to add a complexity :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak in terms of SEO, as I am in no way shape or form a SEO Expert, but I would say things that don't directly have to do with your business, should be on a different site. Business sites really should only be about the business.

You can have an About Me section of the site that discusses your interests, but I would recommend breaking it up into business and personal.

Basically you should have your site split into what it is you're selling and things relevant to it. A Blog about domains and web design is relevant to the service you're offering. However Kayaking and Economics are not, those should be split off.

AS your Kayaking is sponsored by your company, you can link from your personal kayaking to your business site, but not vice-versa. You can discuss your interests in general in your About Me/Us page, but I would stay clear of intertwining them.

Comment: Many Thanks Randy. This is what I expected. Why do you say not to link from the business site to the personal site?

At the moment I have a page on the business website that explains the sponsorship, and the members of the team that we sponsor. What would you propose I do with that?

Comment: I would recommend removing it. In my personal opinion a sponsorship is used as advertising for a company. Many companies will promote things that they sponsor on their site if it is something that will benefit their image to potential clients, or if it's something that has to do with their company values.

Edit: 

In my opinion, unless you're designing sites specifically for sporting teams/groups/events it's not relevant to the business. In general you want the kayaking to be driving traffic to your business, not the other way around...people may forget why they were there in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough :) That makes sense.

Comment: Sorry to keep expanding. I had the company logo expanded upon to a version where the mascot is in a kayak. This logo is on the page on the company website which lists the members etc, and each team member has it on their kit.. on that basis I feel that it should remain somewhere on the business website, yet i see your point of it seemingly lacking relevance if i split up personel/business... if i had a kayaking related website however, it would become relevant .. hmm

Comment: Have that logo on the kayaking site. Its best to keep everything separate.